# Why do Space X starship launches need permission from the FAA?

Tags: spacex, launch, united-states, regulatory, faa

For Flight #7 slated for 02-Feb-2021, Wikipedia's [SpaceX Starship; Testing Program](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SpaceX_Starship#Testing_Program) says:

> SpaceX attempted to fly SN9 on 28 and 29 of January 2021, but failed
> to receive permission from the **FAA.** ([164](https://www.washingtonpost.com/technology/2021/01/28/elon-musk-spacex-starship-faa/), [165](https://www.nasaspaceflight.com/2021/01/starship-sn9-speedy-recovery-static-fire-launch/))

**Q:** Why do Space X starship launches need permission from the [US Federal Aviation Administration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Federal_Aviation_Administration)?

Comment: I would be very concerned if they didn't need to coordinate with the FAA. Seems like it would just be a matter of time before a collision with a plane or other aircraft occurred.

Comment: @PCLuddite - I'd expect a launch area to already be a no-fly zone.

Comment: @Davor not sure how no-fly zones actually work, but I'm sure it involves coordination with the feds, either the FAA or the military or other appropriate dept. And I would think that at least involves notifying the FAA so that pilots actually *know* it's a no fly zone. (although the federal government doesn't exactly have a reputation for common sense).

Comment: See "Temporary Flight Restriction" listed in an answer below. It is a no-fly zone, but only for a set period of time around the launch window.

Comment: well .... it would be a bit strange to ask permission from the UK CAA don't you think?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Because it's required by law ([51 USC Ch. 509: Commercial Space Launch Activities](https://www.govinfo.gov/app/details/USCODE-2010-title51/USCODE-2010-title51-subtitleV-chap509)) and by FAA regulations ([14 CFR Chapter III - Commercial Space Launch Activities, Federal Aviation Administration, Department of Transportation](https://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?gp=&SID=1f58495405665a030c05e44bca5a8591&mc=true&tpl=/ecfrbrowse/Title14/14chapterIII.tpl)) that implement those laws.

Even amateur rockets are subject to some FAA regulations. A rocket going up 10 km is subject to quite a few FAA regulations. Even though SN9 is not going into space (not even close), it has far too much thrust to qualify it as an amateur rocket. The launch of SpaceX's SN9 is categorized as a commercial space launch, and FAA approval is required for that.

**Update**
My answer does not address the issue of "why?" Shortly after aviation started more than a century ago, incidents and even fatalities became ever more frequent occurrences. The US government passed multiple laws, starting with the [Air Mail Act of 1925](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_Mail_Act_of_1925) to attempt to make air travel safer, more common, and more lucrative. And it has worked. US commercial aviation makes about 5670 flights per day, and incidents are extremely rare.

The mindset of the modern Federal Aviation Administration (FAA) goes a bit against the mindset of rocketry. Suppose that one out of every thousand commercial airplane flights results in death to all. Given the current flight rate, that would mean six fatal commercial airplane crashes per day in the US alone. Hardly anybody would fly in a commercial airliner were that the case. Modern aviation is extremely safe. It is arguably the safest mode of transportation.  Suppose even one out of every million commercial flights resulted in multiple fatalities. That would given the modern FAA qualms. With over two million commercial airline flights per year in the US alone, that would mean two major incidents per year, in the US alone.

An incident rate of one out of every thousand rocket launches remains a mere pipe dream. That means that the mentality of the modern FAA, where a one out of a million incident rate would be a bad sign, goes a bit against the grain of current rocket launch statistics. Nonetheless, the US Congress has mandated that the Department of Transportation (and hence the FAA) foster and regulate the commercial space industry.

Comment: Could you expand a bit on why those laws/regulations exist, and why/when approval may be granted or denied?

Comment: @nexus_2006 The FAA is where the buck stops, when an aircraft pilot who was doing nothing illegal didn't realize somebody was playing with rockets that day and found out when the plane was "accidentally" shot down. There is some back story to this situation. SpaceX failed to comply with the terms of the FAA approval for a previous launch (not to mention Musk's repeated public anti-regulation statements) so the FAA wasn't going to cut them any slack this time around.

Comment: I assumed traffic management was at least part of it, but I wasn't sure if a designated spaceport had some kind of R space or special use space like a firing range does.  Thanks for the add'l info, I think it improves the answer to say a bit about why, rather than just "because it's the law".

Comment: @JonathanReez Multiple news outlets are reporting that an FAA spokesperson said "Prior to the Starship SN8 test launch in December, SpaceX sought a waiver to exceed the maximum public risk allowed by federal safety regulations. After the FAA denied the request, SpaceX proceeded with the flight. The FAA required SpaceX to conduct an investigation of the incident after the flight and all testing that could affect public safety at the Boca Chica, Texas, launch site was suspended until the investigation was completed."

Comment: Wow. Are there consequences for proceeding with a launch without a valid permit?

Comment: @OrganicMarble The statement did not say what SpaceX did wrong. There's a lot of online speculation: The launch itself, the bellyflop, and lots of other things. I truly doubt it was the launch itself for which the FAA withdrew a license; if that was the case the FAA would be all over SpaceX's case. That would involve jail time, massive fines, and other huge penalties. So possibly the bellyflop, or possibly something else that the FAA did not like. That the matter was cleared up in less than a week suggests it was not an overly huge issue.

Comment: @OrganicMarble The thing that bugs me most is the apparent arrogance on the side of SpaceX. (Musk's tweets, for example.) The "we're so good we can't fail" arrogance on the part of some in NASA played a big role in causing the Challenger and Columbia disasters.

Comment: @OrganicMarble Well, at *best* assuming nothing goes wrong you've pissed off the FAA and the next time you ask for a launch permission you're going to have to make very sure you've crossed all the 'T's and dotted all the i's or it's going to be rejected. If something *does* go wrong during the launch, you're on the hook for absolutely every single consequence and any 'unforeseeable circumstances' defense attempts lose all their credibility.

Comment: @JonathanReez This is not an unelected bureaucrat acting on a whimsy. This is the FAA acting according to the "take care" clause of the Constitution. Congress has mandated the FAA regarding licensing of launch operators and has mandated the FAA to ensure safety. When a launch operator explicitly violates a launch constraint, the FAA is going to take a harder look.

Comment: @Joshua -- Unless you know why the FAA decided to temporarily block the SN9 test, which you almost certainly do not know because the detailed knowledge most likely is Sensitive But Unclassified (SBU), you shouldn't speculate. There are concepts / designs / implementations that SpaceX, or any launch provider for that matter, must disclose to the FAA / NASA / Air Force / Space Force. Those governmental agencies are obligated not to disclose these technical details to the public. While they can speak in broad terms, they cannot provide details. But you would know this if you worked for the FAA.

Comment: Can anybody confirm my understanding that the FAA is, in fact, enforcing an international agreement? After all, alarming the Russians with an unexpected missile launch would hardly be a good idea.

Comment: @MarkMorganLloyd There are three relevant treaties to which the US is a signatory that do pertain, but this is not the driving reason for the FAA's involvement. The driving reason is that the FAA has been mandated to foster the US commercial space industry, and that means regulating it to some extent. All it would take would be one incident of a launch by a wild wild west US rocket launch company taking down a US commercial airliner full of people to result in widespread public demands for a shut down of  the US commercial rocket launch industry.

Comment: @DavidHammen Thanks for that. Obviously a 10km vertical launch doesn't amount to much but I presume that such a thing would still be recognisable to a satellite monitor. I must admit that the "landing" did look pretty reckless to me, and assume- or at least hope- that the entire facility had been evacuated.

Comment: Interesting thing is that no matter where you go, especially in the US, you're probably never very far from someone flying something, so if you want to launch a rocket, somebody needs to know about it so they can stay clear.

Answer (score 27):

To expand a bit on David Hammen's answer, the reasons for the regulations requiring FAA permits for rocket launches are related to public safety (or sometimes the egos of bureaucrats, but mostly public safety.) There are a couple of particular areas that these fall under:

### Range Safety

Obviously, rockets carry *a lot* of fuel and often very toxic materials (e.g. [hydrazine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrazine) or sometimes even radioactive material for [radioisotope thermoelectric generators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radioisotope_thermoelectric_generator).) Rocket launches [don't always go as planned](https://youtu.be/Ayu0GsrvKQA), which sometimes leads to large explosions and/or highly toxic stuff landing downrange (or just exploding on the launch site.) Thus, making sure that the risk of such an incident harming people and property is minimized is important. The FAA is the U.S. agency in charge of safety for stuff that flies, so this falls under their purview.

### Aviation Safety

Spacecraft tend not to be the only vehicles flying around in the atmosphere. In general, they must share the atmosphere with aircraft, even if only very briefly. When you're flying around in your Cessna (or your Boeing, for that matter,) it's not exactly easy to see and avoid something that suddenly lights up underneath you and accelerates quickly to supersonic speeds straight up in your general direction. Thus, just as aircraft have regulations to prevent them from flying into each other, so, too, do spacecraft have regulations to prevent them from flying into aircraft.

In particular, when a rocket launch is scheduled, a [Temporary Flight Restriction (TFR)](https://www.faa.gov/regulations_policies/advisory_circulars/index.cfm/go/document.information/documentID/1028851) will be issued telling aircraft pilots to stay away from a set boundary of airspace through which the rocket is expected to transit the atmosphere for a set period of time. A [Notice to Airmen (NOTAM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NOTAM) will be issued to advise pilots of the TFR. Checking the current NOTAMs is part of normal preflight procedures for pilots, so this ensures that they'll be aware of the launch (assuming they actually conduct a proper preflight briefing.)

Of course, the FAA is the agency in charge of maintaining aviation safety, so this concern also falls under their area of regulatory authority (and they are the ones who issue the TFRs and NOTAMs.)

In this case, this part of the launch licensure requirement is actually useful to the organization launching the rocket. By getting a temporary flight restriction put in place around the launch site for the desired timeframe, they can ensure that some random guy buzzing around in his 172 isn't going to stray too close to launch site during the launch window. Launch windows are often very short (sometimes even instantaneous,) which means a launch might have to be scrubbed entirely if an airplane wondered too close to the launch site at the wrong time. Having a TFR in effect means that both pilots and air traffic controllers will be aware of the launch in advance and will plan for air traffic to avoid the area during the active time of the TFR, including the launch window.

Comment: Re not being easy to see, my hang-gliding instructor had a war story about that.  Of course you don't cross airspace if you can possibly avoid it, but back in the 80s things were a bit looser, and there was an unwritten rule that if you had to cross an airfield then you went across the middle, perpendicular to the runways.  All the traffic goes up and down at either end, and in the middle is relatively safe.  Fine in theory, until he crossed a military airfield just as a Tornado was taking off.  It lifted off, immediately stood on its tail, and went up vertically past him. Change of underwear!

Comment: @Graham Wow, yikes. For what it's worth, at least here in the U.S., that's still the normal way to cross an airfield in uncontrolled airspace when flying VFR. Military bases are generally controlled here, though.

Comment: An RTG contains radioactive material (usually Pu238), which is not the same thing as nuclear fuel (usually U235) or nuclear weapons material (usually Pu239).

Comment: @DevSolar It's certainly not weapons-grade material, but it's still a nuclear fuel. Regardless, the point was that it's hazardous because of the radioactivity, so I'll just change it to say "radioactive material."

Comment: @reirab "Nuclear fuel" commonly refers to *fissile* material that can sustain a chain reaction. RTGs, do not contain those; their energy comes from the natural decay of the material.

Comment: I think the "or sometimes the egos of bureaucrats, but mostly public safety"  dig is totally uncalled for.

Comment: @user2705196 Trust me, it's a problem that anyone who has dealt with government regulators regularly has run into (probably more than once.) It's amazing what bureaucrats will do to protect or show off their power sometimes. My personal favorite was having all of our exports stopped with no warning or even notification because some bureaucrat thought a piece of electronic test equipment (the kind every RF engineer in the world has on their desk) belonged on the United States Munitions List (the list of things subject to the U.S. International Trade in Arms Regulations.)

Answer (score 5):

Everything that goes above FL 180, about 18'000 feet needs a flight plan, which has to be filed with the FAA that can approve or not

Comment: Are NASA space launches and military space launches included in "everything"?

Comment: @OrganicMarble For the most part, yes. Things are a little trickier with the military, though, since they have their own areas of restricted/prohibited airspace where they can do more or less what they want regardless of what the FAA has to say about it. In general, though, unless they have a good reason not to (e.g. secrecy,) they do try to play nice with the FAA to keep the skies safe for both their pilots and civilian ones.

Comment: In general, though, space launches will get their own TFR (Temporary Flight Restriction) rather than a normal FAA IFR flight plan. NOTAMs (NOTices to AirMen) will be issued for the TFRs. For the permanent restricted/prohibited military airspace, it will be charted on civilian aviation charts and contacts are listed in the chart supplement for civilian pilots to coordinate with the military to make sure we stay out of each other's way.

Comment: There is a big difference, though, between amateur rockers that go above 18000 feet above sea level and commercial rockets. High power amateur rockets need a permit while commercial rockets need a license. Any rocket that can go above some height limit or that has a thrust level greater than some limit makes the rocket "commercial", and that makes the rocket subject to an entirely different and more stringent set of regulations than the regulations for high power amateur rockets.

Comment: @OrganicMarble no, the military is not subject to the FAA. Neither AFAIK is NASA. But as good neighbours they do tend to notify the FAA of their operations unless those operations are secret

Comment: @jwenting so this answer is wrong?

Comment: Key to @jwenting's point here is that even if you don't *have* to, it's still the polite neighborly thing to do. So aside from violating regulations, Musk was deliberately being a jackass.

Comment: @Shadur My understanding was that SpaceX did have a license, but that the FAA deemed that they weren't following some of the terms of that license. As far as I know, they weren't just launching large vehicles up to the tropopause without telling anyone, though. I'm pretty sure they did have a TFR as well as an evacuated exclusion zone on the ground around the launch site.

Comment: @reirab correct. SpaceX thought they were in compliance, the FAA thought otherwise is my understanding. Of course without knowing the internal thoughts (rather than official press releases) of each party it's impossible to be certain, but that's all we have to go on so let's go on it. And yes, there was a TFR and there was an exclusion zone enforced by the local Sheriff's department as well as SpaceX's own security teams.